# for loop in range efficiency

Tags: python, for-loop

doing an online python course and playing around with matplotlib object oriented plots.

have the code

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,4)
```

which gives you an array of axes so you can iterate through your plots.

I've played around with this to try and iterate through and make many plots and assign titles, etc to all of them.

the code I made is here:

```
numplots = 4
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,numplots)

titles = "title_1 title_2 title3 title4".split()
xlabels = "x1 x2 x3 x4".split()
ylabels = "ya y2 y3 y4".split()


for i in range(numplots):
    axes[i].plot(x,y)
    axes[i].set_title(titles[i])
    axes[i].set_xlabel(xlabels[i])
    axes[i].set_ylabel(ylabels[i])
    
plt.tight_layout()
```

which produces the desired output. My question is:

Is "For i in range(n)" the best way to do this? I've found I create these kind of for loops due to my familiarity with matlab, but heard in python it's generally better practice to do something like:

```
for current_axis in axes:
```

but I don't understand how i could then index the titles,xlables,ylabels etc.

Any help/ direction to relevant materials comparing the two for loop methods would be great, thanks!

Note* whilst this is in the context of matplotlib, and info on how to achieve these plots in a better way would be welcome, it's more generally a question about the efficiency of this for loop.

Comment: ... `for index, current_axis in enumerate(axes):` ... if axes are enumerateable

Comment: Indexing is often unpythonic, though not always. Using `enumerate` does give one approach, but in this case what you have is fine. Efficiency isn't really an issue for something like this.

Comment: Also `zip` might be useful here `for current_axis, title, xlabel, ylabel in zip(axes, titles, xlabels, ylabels):`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this for the axis but for the other sequences. Instead of

```
for i in range(numplots):
    axes[i].plot(x,y)
    axes[i].set_title(titles[i])
    axes[i].set_xlabel(xlabels[i])
    axes[i].set_ylabel(ylabels[i])
```

you can do:

```
for i, current_axis in enumerate(axes):
    current_axis.plot(x,y)
    current_axis.set_title(titles[i])
    current_axis.set_xlabel(xlabels[i])
    current_axis.set_ylabel(ylabels[i])
```

Comment: Maybe wrap the contents of the loop as a function

Comment: Perfect! Thanks xqt. Can't believe I was trying to learn to code without using this site, ridiculously useful!